# XML schema regular expression is Perl-ish.Why is this is allowed?

Tags: regex, xml, validation, xsd

Im handling an XSD file for some interchange format. The header says that we are in presence of a document conforming to [XML schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) (the one of 2001, so 1.0) and that this is version 0.4.0 of the document. Furthermore, comment indicates that the document has been created by Altova XMLSpy v2015:

```
<!-- W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2015 rel. 3 (x64) 
     (http://www.altova.com)  Payment Instructions -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="0.4.0">
```

This file defines a type to describe [IBAN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number)s, which is an `xs:string` restricted to match a certain regular expression:

```
<xs:simpleType name="IBANType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="^$||([A-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{2,2}[A-Z0-9]{1,30})||(\.)"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

<strike>Now the regex given does not seem to conform to the rather restricted [standard XML Schema regex](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html). In particular, it uses `^` and `$` and repeat patterns `{x,y}`</strike> **(Correction: repeat patterns are allowed as can be found in [the W3C XSD primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#regexAppendix). This makes the regex a valid XSD regex, albeit one that accepts the string `^$` and that uses too many `|`.)** Indeed, if `||` is replaced by `|`, we get a [Perl regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

1. `^$` == "empty string"
2. or `|`
3. `([A-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{2,2}[A-Z0-9]{1,30})` == 2 x alpha, 2 x digit, 1-30 x alpha or digit
4. or `|`
5. `(\.)` == a dot (grouping parenthesis being superfluous)

This indeed matches the IBAN format and covers the two special cases "missing data" and "missing data, replaced by a dot" (both of which would be more elegantly handled by just leaving the element out, but this is outside of my problem scope).

One expects that an implementation of an XSD validator would complain about such a regex, but no. I get a valid `javax.xml.validation.Validator` from `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory` by processing the XSD file: no problem, no warning, and indeed the validator seems to correctly use that regex to check input.

How is that possible? What specification is being followed here, why does Altova XMLSpy generate such an expression? Are the implementations just being lenient, saying "this looks like a Perl regex, so I will process is as such, see me not care"?

Comment: The @version attribute means "this is version 0.4.0 of this schema", not "this schema conforms to version 0.4.0 of the XSD specification".

Comment: @Michael Thank you, correcting text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a valid XSD regular expression - but it might not mean what the author intended

```
^$||([A-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{2,2}[A-Z0-9]{1,30})||(\.)
```

`^$` are ordinary characters, so this matches the string "^$"

`A||B` means A or nothing or B

`{2,2}` is allowed in the XSD regex dialect

`\.` matches a "." character

Comment: The matching of a '.' character is expected. I will have to test whether the string '^$ '  is accepted by the Validator. And you are right that the range expression `{2,2}` is allowed. I did not have the courage to go through the W3C XSD specification but it's [listed in the primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#regexAppendix). I need to correct the question text.

Comment: Finally got around to testing this. The XSD accepts the character string `^$` as an instance of `IBANType`. Aieeee.

Answer (score 2):

Some XML Schema validation processors, for convenience, outsource the parsing and interpretation of regular expressions to a third-party library, used "as is". This has the consequence that they do not follow the specification exactly in this respect.

Even if a processor is more lenient and accepts a superset of the XML Schema regular expression language, it is highly recommended, when designing schemas, to stick to what the XML Schema specification allows and to avoid using the extra features. This makes sure that other XML Schema processors will be able to accept and treat the schema in the same way (interoperability).

What is more problematic is if an implementation does not accept regular expressions that XML Schema allows, or interprets them differently, because this causes interoperability issues with schemas that are 100% compliant.